# Scanner reads after loop ends

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Scanner.hasNext reads if there is token when there is no token it should end the loop , but getting error no such element found exception but when i switch line 1 and line line 2 i works well .

```
    public class ScannerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true ";
        Long l = 13964599874l;
        s = s + l;

        // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

        // find the next long token and print it
        // loop for the whole scanner
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {

            // if the next is a long, print found and the long
            // LINE 1
            if (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
                System.out.println("Found :" + scanner.nextLong());
            }
            // if no long is found, print "Not Found:" and the token
            // LINE 2
            System.out.println("Not Found :" + scanner.next());

        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Not Found :Hello
Not Found :World!
Found :3
Not Found :+
Not Found :3.0
Not Found :=
Not Found :6.0
Not Found :true
Found :13964599874
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at ScannerDemo.main(ScannerDemo.java:23)
```

Comment: yes got my silly mistake , I am not deleting the question as another one can do this silly thing

Answer (score 1):

use a if else like this

```
if (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
       System.out.println("Found :" + scanner.nextLong());
}else{

      System.out.println("Not Found :" + scanner.next());
}
```

the problem is if there is a nextLong you are calling next 2 times.but at the end there is no more elements.

in your code String is `Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true 13964599874`
think now you call `nextLong` and it found `13964599874` but when you call `next()` again you get the error `NoSuchElementException` why? because the is nothing after `13964599874`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't stop the loop. After it reads the `Long`, it will continue to:
`System.out.println("Not Found :" + scanner.next());`

Fix it by adding `continue` after `System.out.println("Found :" + scanner.nextLong());`

```
        if (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
            System.out.println("Found :" + scanner.nextLong());
            continue;
        }
```